# URL-encoded UTF-8 to non-English converter

Tags: encoding

I have some string like this `%B8%96%E4%B0...`. It's usually seen when using some file transferring tool to download and save non-Engilish filename on hard drive. The tool will convert the original non-English filename to that string, which I am not sure if it's called unicode or something else. (since the unicode should look like &# 22823;&# 23478;&# 22909;)(no space between the hash and following numbers). I was wondering if this is a unicode string. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's URL-encoded UTF-8. You can use `convmv` to change it back to normal text.